# How can I get "written permission" from Google to commercialize my project with Google Assistant SDK?

Tags: actions-on-google, google-assistant-sdk

I want to release the app including the Google Assistant SDK. Google's policy says "Google provides the Assistant API only for developmental use on your Project devices. You may not:commercialize your Project without written permission from Google;", but there isn't any contact form.
How can I get written permission from Google.

Answer (score -1):

You can use the official Google Permission portal: https://www.google.com/permissions/